# Verificar códigos que não estão no banco de dados com uma query

Tags: sql, query

Sei que posso verificar códigos que estão numa tabela e não estão em outra com a seguinte *query*:

```
SELECT cod FROM tabela1 WHERE cod NOT IN (SELECT cod FROM tabela2)
```

Mas como posso verificar os registros que não estão numa tabela mas estão numa lista separada por vírgula?

Exemplo: Digamos que tenho uma tabela **nomes** com os seguintes dados:

```
cod | nome
----|-----------------
1   | César
3   | Maurício
```

E quero fazer uma consulta passando os seguintes códigos `1, 2, 3, 4` esperando que o retorno seja `2, 4` que são os códigos que não estão no banco de dados.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Caso a lista seja fixa, você pode fazer isso com `union`s:

```
select * from (
  select 1 item union
  select 2 union 
  select 3 union
  select 4
)
where item not in (select cod from tabela1)
```

Mas se à medida que a lista se extende, a query vai ficar mais e mais lenta.

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5PcXEWxYa9S4D3NBb5cyxK/0

Comment: Juliano, obrigado por responder a pergunta, mas não coloquei o SGDB porque estou procurando algo mais universal que não esteja apegado ao SGDB nem a uma *procedure*. Ao que parece essa *query* só funciona para o SQLite.

Comment: Seria interessante também poder fazer a consulta passando a lista separada por vírgula.

Comment: Creio que essa solução vai ser sempre idiomática de banco pra banco. À menos que você crie uma tabela só pra gerar esse resultado.